# Align times of two different sensor readings

Tags: python

I have the readings of two sensors, which have different acquisition times but also different rates of acquisition. Here's a toy example.

```
t1   10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
s1   x   x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x 
t2   11 17 18 20 26 34 41 42 43 45 51 
s2   y   y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y
```

Sensor 1 has a regular acquisition interval, however sensor 2 is very irregular, sometimes acquiring data fast and some time having gaps of time without acquisition.

Sensor 2 represents a background signal that I want to substract from sensor 1, but to do that I have to first align the times.

For each reading of sensor 1 I want to use the closest value of sensor 2 (It might happen that some readings of sensor 2 don't get paired to any value of sensor 1, it can also happen that 2 reading odf sensor 1 get paired to the same reading of sensor 2)

My approach so far is to have a loop for each value of sensor 1, and since times are ordered I perform a binary search to find the closest reading of sensor 2.

However this seems to me a common problem, so I'm wondering if there's some library that already implements such alignment of readings instead of making my own.

Comment: numpy could help with the interpolation of sensor 2 values.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Comment: Asking for libraries is off topic - if your solution works you could go the route of codereview but they need far much more code then what you present here. Make sure to read their rules first.